# Primitive Recursive Functions Excercise in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, recursion, primitive

For a functional programming excercise I am required to apply primitive recursive functions in haskell. However I do not quite understand yet the definition (and application) of this type of functions.

We are presented the data type Nat to be used, its constructor is:
**data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat**

To my understanding this means that the type "Nat" can be either a Zero or a Natural Succesor.

Then we have a recursor:

```
recNat :: a -> (Nat -> a -> a) -> Nat -> a
recNat a _ Zero = a
recNat a h (Succ n) = h n (recNat a h n)
```

Which I understand is meant to apply recursion to a function?

And I've also been given an example of an addition function using the recursor:

```
addR :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
addR m n = recNat n (\ _ y -> Succ y) m
```

But I don't get how it works, it uses the recNat function with the given two Nats, and also uses an anonymous function as input for recNat ( that is the part I'm not sure what it does! )

So my main issue is what does this do in the function exactly > **\ _ y -> Succ y**

I'm suppossed to apply this same recursor (RecNat) to apply other operations to *Nat*, but I'm stuck still trying to understand the example!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re right that `data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat` means that a `Nat` may be `Zero` or the `Succ`essor of another `Nat`; this represents natural numbers as a linked list, i.e.:

```
zero, one, two, three, four, five :: Nat

zero  = Zero
one   = Succ Zero                              -- or: Succ zero
two   = Succ (Succ Zero)                       --     Succ one
three = Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))                --     Succ two
four  = Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero)))         --     Succ three
five  = Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))))  --     Succ four
-- …
```

The function of `recNat` is to *fold* over a `Nat`: `recNat z k` takes a `Nat` and “counts down” by ones to the final `Zero`, calling `k` on every intermediate `Succ`, and replacing the `Zero` with `z`:

```
recNat z k three
recNat z k (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero)))

-- by second equation of ‘recNat’:
k two                (recNat z k two)
k (Succ (Succ Zero)) (recNat z k (Succ (Succ Zero)))

-- by second equation of ‘recNat’:
k two                (k one         (recNat z k one))
k (Succ (Succ Zero)) (k (Succ Zero) (recNat z k (Succ Zero)))

-- by second equation of ‘recNat’:
k two                (k one         (k zero (recNat z k zero)))
k (Succ (Succ Zero)) (k (Succ Zero) (k Zero (recNat z k Zero)))

-- by first equation of ‘recNat’:
k two                (k one         (k zero z))
k (Succ (Succ Zero)) (k (Succ Zero) (k Zero z))
```

The lambda `\ _ y -> Succ y` has type `a -> Nat -> Nat`; it just ignores its first argument and returns the successor of its second argument. Here’s an illustration of how `addR` works to compute the sum of two `Nat`s:

```
addR two three
addR (Succ (Succ Zero)) (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero)))

-- by definition of ‘addR’:
recNat three                     (\ _ y -> Succ y) two
recNat (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))) (\ _ y -> Succ y) (Succ (Succ Zero))

-- by second equation of ‘recNat’:
(\ _ y -> Succ y) one         (recNat three                     (\ _ y -> Succ y) one)
(\ _ y -> Succ y) (Succ Zero) (recNat (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))) (\ _ y -> Succ y) (Succ Zero))

-- by application of the lambda:
Succ (recNat three                     (\ _ y -> Succ y) one)
Succ (recNat (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))) (\ _ y -> Succ y) (Succ Zero))

-- by second equation of ‘recNat’:
Succ ((\ _ y -> Succ y) zero (recNat three                     (\ _ y -> Succ y) zero))
Succ ((\ _ y -> Succ y) zero (recNat (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))) (\ _ y -> Succ y) zero))

-- by application of the lambda:
Succ (Succ (recNat three                     (\ _ y -> Succ y) zero))
Succ (Succ (recNat (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))) (\ _ y -> Succ y) zero))

-- by first equation of ‘recNat’:
Succ (Succ three)
Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))))

-- by definition of ‘five’:
five
Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))))
```

As you can see, what’s happening here is we’re essentially taking off each `Succ` from one number and putting it on the end of the other, or equivalently, replacing the `Zero` in one number with the other number, i.e., the steps go like this:

```
1+1+0 + 1+1+1+0           2 + 3
1+(1+0 + 1+1+1+0)      1+(1 + 3)
1+1+(0 + 1+1+1+0)    1+1+(0 + 3)
1+1+(1+1+1+0)        1+1+(3)
1+1+1+1+1+0          5
```

The inner lambda always ignores its first argument with `_`, so it may be simpler to see how this works with a simpler definition of `recNat` that literally replaces `Zero` with a value `z` and `Succ` with a function `s`:

```
recNat' :: a -> (a -> a) -> Nat -> a
recNat' z _ Zero     = z
recNat' z s (Succ n) = s (recNat z s n)
```

Then addition is slightly simplified:

```
addR' m n = recNat' n Succ m
```

This literally says “to compute the sum of `m` and `n`, add one `m` times to `n`”.

You may find it easier to play around with these numbers if you make a `Num` instance and `Show` instance for them:

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}  -- for explicitness

instance Num Nat where

  fromInteger :: Integer -> Nat
  fromInteger n
    | n <= 0    = Zero
    | otherwise = Succ (fromInteger (n - 1))

  (+) :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
  (+) = addR

  (*) :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
  (*) = …  -- left as an exercise

  (-) :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
  (-) = …  -- left as an exercise

  abs :: Nat -> Nat
  abs n = n

  signum :: Nat -> Nat
  signum Zero   = Zero
  signum Succ{} = Succ Zero

  negate :: Nat -> Nat
  negate n = n  -- somewhat hackish

instance Show Nat where
  show n = show (recNat' (+ 1) 0 n :: Int)
```

Then you can write `2 + 3 :: Nat` and have it display as `5`.

Comment: This has been beyong useful! Thank you very much!
Also, I've been trying to implement a factorial with this explanation, would you maybe happen to know what I'm doing wrong?

`factR Zero = Succ Zero
factR (Succ m) = recNat (Succ m) (\ _ y -> y) (factR m)`

and also:

`factR Zero = Succ Zero
factR (Succ m) = recNat m (\ _ y -> Succ y) (factR m)`

Answer (score 2):

Roughly, `recNat x f n` computes

```
f (n-1) (f (n-2) (f (n-3) (... (f 0 x))))
```

So, it applies `f` to `x` for `n` times, each time also passing a "counter" as the first argument of `f`.

In your case `\_ y -> ...` ignores the "counter" argument. Hence

```
addR m n = recNat n (\ _ y -> Succ y) m
```

can be read as "to compute `m+n`, apply `m` times the function `Succ` to `n`". This effectively computes `((n+1)+1)+1...` where there are `m` ones in the sum.

You can try to compute the product of two naturals in a similar way. Use `\_ y -> ...` and express multiplication as repeated addition. You'll need to use the already-defined `addR` for that.

Additional hint: after multiplication, if you want to compute the predecessor `n-1`, then the "counter" argument will be very handy, so don't discard that and use `\x y -> ...` instead. After that, you can derive (truncated) subtraction as repeated predecessor.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm very grateful